# How to achieve unique manyToMany in doctrine

Tags: doctrine, unique, relation

In doctrine I have a manyToMany association

```
Document:
manyToMany:
        tags:
          targetEntity: Tag
          inversedBy: tags
          joinTable:
              name: documents_tags
Tag:
manyToMany:
        documents:
          targetEntity: Document
          mappedBy: tags
```

and that creates a new table `documents_tags` with a primary key on `document_id+tag_id` and normal keys on each of them. But I would like to have a unique key constraint over the two columns `tag_id` and `document_id`. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

ok I can answer it myself, it revealed to me when I edited my question: The primary key already is unique of course, so its working already.